# RetryCancel MessageBox

Tags: c#, messagebox

Im using `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show()` to display a dialog to the user. One overload lets me set the buttons that appear using the `System.Windows.MessageBoxButton` enum. However, it seems to lack a `RetryCancel` option that my googling suggests it should have.

- Am I missing something?
- How do I display a RetryCancel messagebox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. There's a [RetryCancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) value:

```
MessageBox.Show("text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
```

Remark: Do not mistake with WPF's [MessageBoxButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxbutton.aspx) enumeration which doesn't have such value.

Comment: "best overload has invalid arguments", seems to lack the one that accepts **MessageBoxButtons**. Wrong version of the framework?

Comment: I don't know which version you are using but the method's definitely there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx

Comment: Your remark is correct, I had confused the WPF and the WinForms MessageBox.

Comment: That's System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.  OTOH, the asker appears to have been trying to use System.Windows.MessageBox, which seems to be part of WPF.  Mixing WPF and Winforms feels like an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Windows` is WPF. `System.Windows.Forms` is WinForms.

Comment: Correct, the WinForms MessageBox had more options, one of them was the one I was looking for.